# No lore in minecraft clans when there should be

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm playing the clans game on the mineplex server, I look at the items at the shop, there should be lore text to see how much they cost, there is not any. this has never happened before. I'm the only person with this problem.

Comment: Post this on mineplex forums

Answer (score 0):

You should post this to [Mineplex Forums](http://www.mineplex.com/forums/m/11929946/viewforum/6882085)

> I'm the only person with this problem.

You aren't. I have the same problem and the only way to fix this, is reporting this bug on forums.